# why do I get 'make: echo: Command not found' when I run 'make'?

Tags: makefile

Here is my Makefile code:

```
PATH = $(shell pwd)

run: 
    echo $(PATH)
```

I run `make` command and I get

```
echo /home/jht/test/makefile
make: echo: Command not found
make: *** [current_path.mk:5: run] Error 127
```

I am sure that I use `Tab` key not `Space`, and I run `echo /home/jht/test/makefile`, then I get `/home/jht/test/makefile` successfully.If I use `echo "$(PATH)"`, I can get the expected result.

So, why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

With...

```
PATH = $(shell pwd)
```

you explicitly set the `PATH` variable to the current working directory.  That is then passed to the shell when you try to run...

```
echo $(PATH)
```

Hence, the shell can no longer locate `echo` (or anything else for that matter).  Choose a variable name that's less likely to conflict with the current environment...

```
CURRENT_DIRECTORY = $(shell pwd)

run: 
    echo $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
```

Comment: Or, just use the predefined `CURDIR` make variable.

Comment: Oh...It's a bad variable name.I wasn't aware of the problem.It's a good idea to modify the name.But I have another question, when I use `PATH = "$(shell pwd)"`(double quotes are added) in Makefile and execute `make run`, I get a correct result.In this case, I modify the `PATH` but I can still locate `echo` command.I'm confused.